# Implementing AccessibilityNodeProvider with virtual children, while supporting TalkBack

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility

I'm trying to implement a custom View for my app. For context, I'm essentially trying to make a simple UI framework with C++ where all GUI is rendered by raw Vulkan. But in this particular example, I just want to focus on the pure Kotlin/Java side of things. I'm investigating how I can expose proper accessibility controls completely programmatically, while using only my singular View.

I've been trying to implement the AccessibilityNodeProvider interface, I have a minimal example included below.I have managed to get the node-info tree working so that the inspector app "Accessibility Tester" is able to see my UI tree. There's one caveat, it does not list my element as "Screen reader focusable" even though I've explicitly set this to true in the code. Other than that, it seems to work correctly.

Now, the main issue I'm facing is that TalkBack is unable to read my contents out loud. I've tried looking at the debug logs TalkBack and found some interesting notes, but nothing that actually pointed at the problem.I'm hoping to get some pointers or advice on what I'm doing wrong. Below is a minimal example of the code, which reproduces the problem. I've tried to keep it as as simple as possible: It's an empty View, where the root itself should act as a "layout/container" item for a singular virtual child, and this virtual child should have behavior similar to a TextView. I've tried a few variations of this code, since this is the example I'm continually working on, but not found any solutions yet.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val view = CustomView(this)
        setContentView(view)
        view.requestFocus()
        view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED)
        view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.CONTENT_CHANGE_TYPE_SUBTREE)
    }
}

class CustomView : View {
    var stringA_ = "Text A"
    val noFocus_ = -10
    var accessFocused_ = noFocus_
    val paint_ = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = 0xFF000000.toInt() // Set your text color here
        textSize = 40f // Set your text size here
    }
    val CHILD_ID = 1
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawText(this.stringA_, 0f, 50f, this.paint_)
    }

    override fun getAccessibilityNodeProvider(): AccessibilityNodeProvider {
        return MyAccessibilityNodeProvider(this)
    }
}

class MyAccessibilityNodeProvider(var view: CustomView) : AccessibilityNodeProvider() {
    override fun createAccessibilityNodeInfo(virtualViewId: Int): AccessibilityNodeInfo? {
        if (virtualViewId == HOST_VIEW_ID) {
            val out = AccessibilityNodeInfo(view, virtualViewId)
            //this.view.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(out)
            out.addChild(this.view, this.view.CHILD_ID)

            out.isFocusable = false
            out.isFocused = false
            out.isVisibleToUser = false
            out.isAccessibilityFocused = false
            out.uniqueId = null
            return out
        }
        if (virtualViewId == this.view.CHILD_ID){
            val out = AccessibilityNodeInfo(view, virtualViewId)
            out.packageName = this.view.context.packageName
            out.className = this.view.javaClass.name
            out.setParent(this.view, HOST_VIEW_ID)
            out.text = this.view.stringA_
            out.contentDescription = "Text widget 0"
            out.uniqueId = "0"
            val textBounds = Rect()
            this.view.paint_.getTextBounds(out.text, 0, out.text.length, textBounds)
            out.setBoundsInScreen(Rect().apply {
                left = 0
                top = 110
                right = 400
                bottom = top + 200
            })
            out.contentDescription = "The text of the virtual child"
            out.isVisibleToUser = true
            out.isEnabled = true
            out.isScreenReaderFocusable = true
            if (this.view.accessFocused_ == virtualViewId) {
                out.isAccessibilityFocused = true
            }
            return out
        }

        return null
    }

    override fun performAction(virtualViewId: Int, action: Int, arguments: Bundle?): Boolean {
        if (action == AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS && virtualViewId == this.view.CHILD_ID) {
            this.view.accessFocused_ = virtualViewId
            // Notify that the accessibility focus has changed
            this.view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)
            return true
        }

        if (action == AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLEAR_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS) {
            this.view.accessFocused_ = this.view.noFocus_
            this.view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED)
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing this interface, setting the corresponding properties and handling the corresponding accessibility events.

My expectation is that TalkBack will send the corresponding event to apply accessibility-focus to my virtual child, I handle the event, and then TalkBack will speak the content out loud. In this case, that content should be "Text A".

Instead, TalkBack fires these events correctly, but after I handle them, TalkBack does nothing. Furthermore, TalkBack does not highlight the area around my virtual child like it does with pure Views.

Answer (score 0):

At first,you should call OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo of your provider:

```
                AccessibilityNodeInfo info = AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain(MyView.this,virtualViewId);
                onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info.unwrap());
```

Also instead of:

```
this.view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)
```

you should,in my opinion,use method sendAccessibilityEventForVirtualView(type,virtualViewId). Also the same you should use to clear accessibility focus. Bellow code of my method,which i implemented in custom view (also you should use it in onHoverEvent or in dispatchHowerEvent). You should adapt this for your variable and for kotlin.

```
    private void sendAccessibilityEventForVirtualView(int eventType, int virtualViewId) {
        if (getParent() != null && ((AccessibilityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)).isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
            AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(eventType);
            event.setPackageName(getContext().getPackageName());
event.setSource(MyView.this, virtualViewId);
            if(event.getEventType() ==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED ||event.getEventType() ==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) accessibilityFocusedId=virtualViewId;
            getParent().requestSendAccessibilityEvent(MyView.this, event);
        }
```